# While using rspec i am constantly getting the same error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the same Error on running rspec that is :-

"Undefined Method - authorize_manage_partner_links"

I am using CANCAN gem in my Gemfile for authorization purposes and i am using Rails version 3.2 and Ruby version 1.9.2.

Please suggest what to do as i am totally new to rspec and rails. I am using a testing database, on importing the database for the first time, when i am running rspec it is showing successful but after that it is showing this error on running the same rspec file. I am using FactoryGirl. and i have defined everything in my factoryrb file as well.

This is my controller--

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

class PartnerLinksController < ApplicationController
    #load_and_authorize_resource
  before_filter :authorize_manage_partner_links!
  layout "backoffice"

  def index
    @partner_links = PartnerLink.all

    if params[:sortby]
      @partner_links = @partner_links.sort_by {|p| p.name} if params[:sortby] == "up"
      @partner_links = @partner_links.sort_by {|p| p.name}.reverse if params[:sortby] == "down"
    else
      @partner_links = @partner_links.sort_by {|p| p.name}
    end
    total = @partner_links.size
    @partner_links = @partner_links.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)

    page = params[:page]
    if !page
      page = 1
    end
    render :locals => {:total => total, :page => page, :sortby => params[:sortby], :partner_link => @partner_link}
  end

  def new
    @partner_link = PartnerLink.new
  end

  def edit
    @partner_link = PartnerLink.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @partner_link = PartnerLink.new(params[:partner_link])
    if @partner_link.save
      redirect_to partner_links_url
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    @partner_link = PartnerLink.find(params[:id])
    if @partner_link.update_attributes(params[:partner_link])
      redirect_to partner_links_url
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @partner_link = PartnerLink.find(params[:id])
    @partner_link.destroy
    redirect_to partner_links_url
  end
end
```

This is my rspec controller that i am using--

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe PartnerLinksController do

    before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:partner_link)
        role_permission
        admin_role  
        user        
        currency
        category
        merchant
        cart
        deal    
        sign_in user
    end

 let(:role_permission) {FactoryGirl.create(:role_permission)}
 let(:currency) {FactoryGirl.create(:currency)}
 let(:merchant) {FactoryGirl.create(:merchant)}
 let(:cart) {FactoryGirl.create(:cart)}
 let(:deal) {FactoryGirl.create(:deal)}
 let(:category) {FactoryGirl.create(:category)}
 let(:authentication) {FactoryGirl.create(:authentication)}
 let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
 let(:admin_role) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role)}

   describe "index" do

    it "Should display all the partner links" do

        get :index
        end
    end

       describe "new" do

    it "Should create all the partner links" do
        get :new
        end
    end

       describe "create" do

    it "Should create new all the partner links" do
        get :create
        end
    end

          describe "update" do

    it "Should update all the partner links" do
        get :update
        end
    end

          describe "destroy" do

    it "Should delete all the partner links" do
        get :destroy
        end
    end
end
```

app/models/partner_link.rb--

```
class PartnerLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  validates_presence_of :name, :url, :description
end
```

This is my Gemfile--

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.2'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'authlogic'
gem "devise"
gem "devise-encryptable"
gem "devise-async"
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem "cancan"
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'oauth2'
#gem 'fastercsv' #no-longer required after ruby 1.9
gem 'pg'
#gem 'thin'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'haml-rails' # Use HAML instead of ERB for templates
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'
gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development
#gem "pdfkit"
gem "pdfkit", "~>  0.5.0"
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'sendgrid', "~> 1.0.1"
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
#gem 'roadie' #fixing email css

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'

  # Database Cleaner clears the database between tests. This done because we have
  # to set config.use_transactional_fixtures = false in the spec_helper file.
  # The use_transactional_fixtures value is set to false because Selenium test
  # driver cannot access the test records created via database transactions.
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :test do
#  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'

  # As we’re using Capybara we can call the save_and_open_page method at any
  # point and this will open the page in a browser so that we can take a look
  # at it. This is enabled by Launchy.
#  gem 'launchy'

#  gem 'rspec-mocks'
end
gem "less-rails"
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '>= 2.0.3'

gem 'rb-readline', '~> 0.5.0', require: 'readline'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.3"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end



gem "mail", "~> 2.4.4"
gem 'jquery-rails'

#gem "mocha", :group => :test

gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'acts_as_xlsx'
gem "httparty"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'font_assets'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'mailchimp-api', require: 'mailchimp'
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem "rails_best_practices"
```

Comment: please, provide code from your `PartnerLink` model

Comment: Looks like authorize_manage_partner_links method is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Yes, i have updated the model. please do check. @Nikita

Comment: @Sajin Yes u r right, authorize_manage_partner_links method is not defined anywhere that is because we are taking this directly from the Gemfile. Even though the method is not defined anywhere the application is running smoothly.